# Many errors in WAMP for php on a specific PC

Tags: php, mysql, wamp

I have installed WAMP server to work on php, but there are some issues. First of all, the WAMP icon doesn't turns green as i start WAMP, it remains red/orange all the time, I have tried many things but nothing worked. To be more clear, although the icon remains orange it opens localhost and phpMyAdmin in the browser, but when I try to access my php files it shows many weird errors (syntax and others). Those files run on other systems perfectly so there should be no such error on my system. Some errors are:

```
Notice: Undefined index: uid in C:\wamp\www\MI\accesscontrol.php on line 17
```

And

```
Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in C:\wamp\www\MI\rs.php on line 2
```

These errors don't occur on other PCs.
Please suggest something to fix both icon and error issues.
Thanks!

Comment: Your other computer must be running an older version of PHP.  The answer to one of the issues is in the message `use mysqli or PDO`. The undefined index means you have an array but it doesn't have the `uid` index. Without code can't tell ya much more..

Comment: Or the other server had another error level or errors were totaly switched off. You could check the settings in your php.ini file.

Comment: ; display_errors
;   Default Value: On
;   Development Value: On
;   Production Value: Off         should i edit all errors off?

Comment: Do you want to fix the problems or just not see the errors?

Comment: i want both if possible for me @chris85

Comment: So issue 1, switch your database calls and connection to `PDO` or `mysqli_` either or, just not `mysql_`. Issue two you have something like `$array['uid']` but `uid` doesn't exist in `$array` so it is inaccessible. Once those are changed error will be gone. If the is a production machine I'd turn off display errors and only log them. If the is development machine than logging and displaying makes sense.

Comment: @MarcB There was more to this question than just the usual Undefined variable and Undefined Index issues.

Answer (score 1):

Any error starting with :-

```
Notice: Undefined index:
```

are errors that **do exist on your other system(s)** but you have configured the other server **Not to show errors** its how a LIVE server should be configured but not how a **Development** server should be configured. WAMPServer is of course a development server.

It either shows the code was developed badly, or on a live server where errors are not shown to the screen. However check the live servers `php_error.log` and they will be shown in there, assuming that was not also turned off.

Anyway the correct solution is to *Fix the Errors* while the *quick and dirty solution* is to tell PHP not to show these errors to the screen.

Edit `php.ini` (using the wampmanager menus ) and find this line

```
display_errors = On
```

and change it to

```
display_errors = Off
```

The errors starting

```
Deprecated:
```

Are showing because the code was developed in an older version of PHP and the code being used contains code that will soon be removed from PHP.

So again the *correct solution* would be to refactor the code to use either the MYSQLI_ or PDO extensions to get to a MySQL database. If there is not time to do this, you can stop these errors being generated with another change to the `php.ini` file

Find this line

```
error_reporting = E_ALL
```

and change it to

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED
```

Now there is the issue of the Wampmanager icon not moving to a GREEN state.

If the wampmanager icon stays ORANGE then one of the services ( wampapache or wampmysqld) has not started correctly. As you can see localhost I would suggest that it is MYSQL that has not started. If that is the case, look at `mysql log` ( using wampmanager menus) or if that is empty, the "Windows Event Log"  for error messages from MYSQL.

You may need to ask another question if you cannot work out a solution to that error, but a couple of things to look for are :-

1. Have you got another MySQL running on your PC
2. Is there a rouge `my.ini` in the `C:/windows` folder somewhere. If so delete it.